FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'patchelf' while building TensorFlow from source
Description:
I am trying to build TensorFlow 2.18 from source on CentOS 8 with the following environment:
Python Version: 3.10,
Bazel Version: 6.5.0,
CUDA/cuDNN Version: CUDA 12.5 / cuDNN 9.3,
GCC/Compiler Version: gcc 8.5.0,
GPU: Tesla V100 SXM2 16GB,
I have installed patchelf, verified its installation, and added it to the PATH environment variable.
bazel --output_base=/goutam/bazel_cache build    --repo_env=WHEEL_NAME=tensorflow     --config=cuda     --repo_env=HERMETIC_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES=sm_70     --config=cuda_wheel   --verbose_failures     //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:wheel

[goutam@Goutam]$ patchelf --version patchelf 0.17.0

[goutam@Goutam]$ which patchelf
/Goutam/patchelf/bin/patchelf

Despite verifying that patchelf is installed and its path is correctly exported, the build process fails with the following error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'patchelf'. Even when specifying the path to patchelf explicitly using --action_env=PATCHELF=/Goutam/bin/patchelf, the issue persists.

Looks like it is looking at /storage/Goutam/bin/patchelf whereas you have it at /Goutam/patchelf/bin/patchelf
